# How to get relevant search in mysql full text search?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I want relevancy for exact "production house in goa". it also results anything that contain Goa.

```
SELECT * FROM `app_search` WHERE MATCH (`keywords`) AGAINST
("production house in goa" in boolean mode) 
order by MATCH (`keywords`) AGAINST ("production house in goa" in boolean mode)
desc, rank desc;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Deleting old table and recreating with fulltext index on keywords and below query solve the problem.

```
SELECT *, MATCH (`keywords`) AGAINST
('software development in florida'
IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score
FROM `ftextsearch` WHERE MATCH (keywords) AGAINST
('software development in florid'
IN BOOLEAN MODE) order by score desc,rank desc
```

Query also return relevancy of search in score.